# How to add checking in axios request interceptors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-context

I am using `axios.interceptors` and `useContext` to handle the request loading spin component in my React.js project.

When the request start, I set the context value - `showLoading` `true`, and change to `false` if it finished or error. The function works perfectly. Here is my sample code:

```
// Request
  axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {     
        setGlobalLoading(true)
        return request;
    }, error => {
        setGlobalLoading(false);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });

// Response
  axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
        setGlobalLoading(false);
        return response;
    }, error => {
        setGlobalLoading(false);

        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

However, I have a page which is a table, and it need to call multiple api on each row, and all the api return so fast. Then it make the loading component "blinking".

So I have an idea, can I make "Only show the loading if the request take more than 1 second " or I should set the delay to close the loading? (But I don't know how to get any pending requests, because this may close the loading when another request not finish)

The callback function only call once, should I use the context or state to save the `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` functions? or any better solution to handle this case?

Answer (score -1):

you can create a array to save requset.
Usually request has a request id,you can use this request id.
if you send a request ,you can push request to array,in finally you can remove this request .
if this array.length >0 loading is show .else loading is close